# Qlik sense: How to aggregate strings into single row in script

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I am trying to aggregate strings that belong to the same product code in one row. Which Qlik sense aggregation function should I use?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1rmy.png)

I am able to aggregate integers in such example, but failed for string aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [maxstring()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/StringAggregationFunctions/maxstring.htm) - this is a [string aggregation function](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringAggregationFunctions/string-aggregation-functions.htm).

Answer (score 0):

As x3ja [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74480661/11486874), you can use an aggregation function in charts that [will work for strings](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringAggregationFunctions/string-aggregation-functions.htm), including:

- [`MaxString()`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringAggregationFunctions/MaxString.htm)
- [`Only()`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/BasicAggregationFunctions/only.htm)
- [`Concat()`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/StringAggregationFunctions/concat.htm)

These can result in the type of thing you're looking for:
[image: Screenshot of Qlik table results]

It's worth noting, though, that this sort of problem is almost always an issue with the underlying data model. Depending on what your source data looks like, you should consider investigating your use of [`Join`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/Join.htm) and/or [`Concatenate`](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/concatenate.htm). You can see more info on how to use those functions on [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/combine-tables-join-keep.htm).

Here's a very basic example of using a `Join` to properly combine the data in a way that results in all data showing up a single record without needing any aggregations in the table chart:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik script JOIN example]